# Object identity is already associated with an acl

Tags: php, symfony, acl, event-listener

i try to create 3 functions for the ACL Management.

```
public function postPersist(LifeCycleEventArgs $event){
    $em = $event->getEntity();
    $entity = $event->getEntity();

    $aclProvider = $this->container->get('security.acl.provider');
    $objectIdentity = ObjectIdentity::fromDomainObject($entity);

    try {
        $acl = $aclProvider->findAcl($objectIdentity);
    } catch (AclNotFoundException $e) {
        $acl = $aclProvider->createAcl($objectIdentity);
    }

    $securityContext = $this->container->get('security.context');
    $token = $securityContext->getToken();
    $securityIdentity = UserSecurityIdentity::fromToken($token);

    $acl->insertObjectAce($securityIdentity, MaskBuilder::MASK_OWNER);
    $aclProvider->updateAcl($acl);
}
```

Whenever one User create something, the ACL is created by the service.(Eventlistener)

But now I have a little problem.
I DROP the hole MySQL-DB and whenever I would create a new Entity I become the following error message.

> There is no ACL for the given object identity.

Then i delete the try and catch from this function and only let createACL, then i get

> Object identity is already associated with an acl

I dont understand this, course my DB is empty...

Tanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried clearing your entire cache in addition to dropping the DB?

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I got the same Error "There is no ACL for the given object identity."